# Creating multiple workers and a cache Job in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, redis, google-kubernetes-engine

The past few days I've been struggling to build a Kubernetes solution for my use case. For clarity, the plan is to run this in GKE.

There is finite work to do for each request. On each request, I'd like to create multiple workers, which communicate over a Redis cache. When all work is done, it should mostly exit/destroy itself, as much as possible.

It seems like a very easy and common problem, but I can't find a fitting solution.

As for the workers, a Job seems to be a good solution, since it can start and end based on each of the pod states. Sadly I wasn't able to define a singular cache for that Job, since it then would be started on each worker pod, which defeats the purpose.

Starting a single Pod with the Redis cache is discouraged in the docs since it is not restored when something bad happens.

The only idea I have right now is to define a completely separate Deployment with a single Redis pod, wait until it is initialized and ready to work, then create a Job. After that, the last worker calls an external function, which can then destroy this whole assembly.
I'm discouraged to use this kind of approach since it has way too much space for any part of it to break and leave any kind of mangled mess behind.

What would be the intended way to solve this?

Comment: Can you clearly say what's your goal here and the question (questions ?). What have you tried already ? Provide as much details as possible - right now it's hard to understand what do you want to do.

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor After struggling with Kubernetes API, documentation, and overall complexity/abstraction of concepts for several weeks, I've found just using docker swarm way more compelling for my use case.
With my new experience gained, using Kubernetes only starts to make sense on a pretty large scale.